# using Oracle sysdate with Nhibernate Linq

Tags: linq, nhibernate

When creating a Linq expression in Nhibernate 3.2,  is there way to pass the sysdate as part of the generated sql?

For example, something like this

```
from c in _session.Query<Question> 
where Question.EDate.Date = sysdate
```

or

```
from c in _session.Query<Question> 
where Question.Edate.Date == trunc(sysdate)
```

to generate a select statement like:

```
select * from question where trunc(EDate) == trunc(sysdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only by extending the LINQ provider (not that difficult):

http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.pt/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html
http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-3-extending-linq-provider-fix-notsupportedexception